# Randomly run into Runtime Eror 1004

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm writing code in VBA that goes through files in a directory and harvests info. I'm using a boilerplate drill down and it works for almost every file, but for some of them, I run into runtime error 1004. Does anyone have any advice for debugging? I've already adjusted the macro settings on the files that cause the errors. The code is included below.

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        
            If LCase(Right(oFile.Name, 4)) = "xlsx" Then
        
            length = UBound(Inspections)
    
            ReDim Preserve Inspections(length + 1)
            ReDim Preserve fridgeDoc(length + 1)
            ReDim Preserve fridgeWalk(length + 1)
            ReDim Preserve nrgEff(length + 1)
            ReDim Preserve mheDoc(length + 1)
            ReDim Preserve mheWalk(length + 1)
            ReDim Preserve buildingDoc(length + 1)
            ReDim Preserve buildingWalk(length + 1)
            
            Workbooks.Open oFile
        
            Inspections(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(11, 7).Value
            fridgeDoc(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(12, 7).Value
            fridgeWalk(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(13, 7).Value
            nrgEff(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(14, 7).Value
            mheDoc(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(15, 7).Value
            mheWalk(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(16, 7).Value
            buildingDoc(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(17, 7).Value
            buildingWalk(length) = Workbooks(oFile.Name).Worksheets(1).Cells(18, 7).Value
            
            Workbooks(oFile.Name).Close
            
            End If
Next oFile
```

As stated before, I've tried adjusting the macro settings on the adjusted files.

Comment: Side note, but it would be a lot better to use a `Workbook` variable here.

Comment: Also `ReDim Preserve` is an expensive operation. It's likely your approach can be optimized to size the arrays appropriately before looping.

Comment: Do any of the cells have something like `#N/A` or `#VALUE?`  in them?

Comment: Runtime error 1004 is generic; it could be caused by any of a number of issues. Tell us what line generates the error. And when it fails, verify that you can open the target workbook manually, and that the source workbook has valid data in the relevant cells.

Comment: As @BigBen noted: `Dim` a long integer `lngFileCount`, set `lngFileCount=oFolder.Files.Count` and `Redim` each array **ONCE, BEFORE** the loop: `Redim Inspections(lngFileCount)`. (But fix the error first!)

Comment: @RichardCook might need to adjust by 1 for a zero based array, or specify the lower bound, but yes.

Comment: Please share the error description and on which line the error occurs. Please share at least the preceding code (preferably the whole) and how you plan to use the octet of arrays in the continuation of the code. It seems that the code could be simplified using a single jagged array holding 2D arrays holding the values of the single-column eight-cell ranges.

Comment: @braX No, the affected sheets don't have a null value in the proper location.

Comment: @RichardCook The line at which the error generates is Workbooks.Open oFile, and I can open up the sheet afterwards. Also, I don't believe this would be the issue based on where the code fails but there are relevant values where I'm looking in these sheets.